# Сжатие без потери качества

Tags: php

Подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь алгоритм сжатия изображений и видео с минимальной потерей качества, для фото такое используется на фото хостингах, вконтакте и других соц сетях. Подскажите, как можно такое реализовать или у этого алгоритма есть название и готовое решение? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Это называется thumbnail - превью изображения
Я делаю это вот так.

```
<?php
function createThumbs($imga, $thumbWidth){
      // load image and get image size
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imga);
      $width = imagesx($img);
      $height = imagesy($img);

      // calculate thumbnail size
      $new_width = $thumbWidth;
      $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width));

      // create a new temporary image
      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height);

      // copy and resize old image into new image 
      imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
$newfile=basename($imga);
      // save thumbnail into a file
      imagejpeg($tmp_img, $newfile);
return $newfile;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

png. без потеря качества. для картинок.

для видео ищите lossless video codec в гугле. Например, x264 (h264).